# My app crashes when I change from AppCompatActivity to Fragment

Tags: android

I was following a tutorial since I'm new to developing apps in Android Studio, and I saw that my class had `extends AppCompatActivity`, so I decided to change it to `extends Fragment`, without it showing me an error inside the class.

The problem is that when I run the application, it opens correctly, but when I want to show the view that belongs to that Fragment, the app crashes, that is, it closes by itself and stops debugging. I've tried to put breakpoints but the app closes before.

This is my class:

```
public class Register extends Fragment {

    private EditText dni;
    private EditText contrasenia;
    private EditText peso;
    private EditText altura;
    private EditText sexo;
    private EditText mail;
    private UserBusiness userBusiness;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_registrarse, container, false);
        dni = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.idDni);
        contrasenia = (EditText)  view.findViewById(R.id.idContrasnia);
        peso = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.idPeso);
        altura = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.idAltura);
        sexo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.idSexo);
        mail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.idMail);
        return view;
    }
```

And this is my `main_activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void Register(View view){
        Intent register = new Intent(this, Registrarse.class);
        startActivity(register);
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me, please?

The LogCat says:

```
2022-11-02 18:37:25.381 11088-11088/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.seminario, PID: 11088
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.seminario/com.example.seminario.Registrarse}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.seminario.Registrarse cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.seminario.Registrarse cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
```

I saw that the problem was because I had a `startActivity()` instead of `startService()`, so I changed but now it does not crashes but nothing happens

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: @TheLibrarian I posted what the LogCat says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the problem. You can't start a fragment like an activity or change an activity to fragment and activity must be defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

If you want to create a fragment, it must be long to an activity. So you need to create an activity host for `Register` fragment first and then inflater it in that activity. For more fragment details: [Fragments from Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments)